# Dynamically add a property to a class

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties

What would be the best way to create a property of class dynamically?

I have to create JSON data based on which there will be a webhook push message.
I've created 2 classes, each of them have multiple properties, the problem is that even if property is not filled (NULL by default), webhook push has wrong format. To avoid it I have to create properties depending on needs.

Is there any method which will allows that?
To picture what I need:

```
public class ChannelSettings
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public AttachSettings attachments { get; set; } //Here I would like to this property to be dynamic
}

public class AttachSettings
{
    public string fallback { get; set; }
    public string pretext { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author_name { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string author_icon { get; set; }
}
public string GenJSON(ChannelSettings channelSet)
{
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channelSet);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This would be easier to visualise if you added some example data and what you expected the JSON to look like...

Comment: "webhook push have wrong format" I don´t understand what this means. Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: `even if property is not filled (NULL by default)`. Are you sure? It seems the property is present in the json. Otherwise it wouldn't be a problem. IMO the question should not be `how to add a property to a class` but rather `how to define the properties that need to be serialized`.

Comment: OK, so basicaly if no data in attach is added then i've have that kind of JSON:"{\"channel\":null,\"username\":\"user\",\"text\":\"test text\",\"attachments\":[{\"fallback\":null,\"pretext\":null,\"text\":null,\"title\":null,\"author_name\":null,\"image_url\":null,\"author_icon\":null,\"fields\":[]}]}",  and what i want here is that : "{\"channel\":null,\"username\":\"user\",\"text\":\"test text\"}" so there is no need to att attachment section while there is no data

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
    dynamic expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
    expandoObject.NewProperty =  "newValue";
```

I think the [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/) help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood this correctly but why don't you make this property optional?
Just use AttachSettings? and all should be fine.

Comment: Because the class will serialized to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you actually want is for the `AttachSettings` to be a dictionary or something?:

```
public class ChannelSettings
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> attachments { get; set; } 
}

public ChannelSettings GetData()
{
    return new ChannelSettings
    {        
        channel="one", username="user", text="text",
        attachments= new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"fallback","somevalue"},
            {"author_name","some author"},
            {"shoe_size","12},
            //...etc...
        }
    }
}

public string GenJSON(ChannelSettings channelSet)
{
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channelSet);
    return output;
}
```

This should produce JSON a bit like this:

```
{
    "channel":"one",
    "username":"user",
    "text":"text",
    "attachments":[
        "fallbackvalue":"somevalue",
        "author_name":"some author",
        "shoe_size":"12"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't have problem with JSON string while there is data in Attachments, problem is while there is no data, then i have mess with lots of null values. Please check example i'hve added under the main message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make parameter type as dynamic and serialize and deserialize it as below :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channelSettings = new ChannelSettings();

        channelSettings.attachments = new AttachSettings();
        channelSettings.attachments.fallback = "test";


        var testSerialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channelSettings);

        dynamic testDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(testSerialize);

        Console.WriteLine(testDeserialize.attachments.fallback); // here you can access the parameters
    }
}

public class ChannelSettings
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public dynamic attachments { get; set; } //Here i would like to this property was dynamic
}
```

The output is : test

Also @GPW has another solution using dictionary which good for unknown type/size of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think off is [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2). It seems to be there to work with any weakly typed WebService and you did mention JSON.

Internallty it seems to be little more then a `Dictionary<string, object>` with some Syntax sugar, change noficiation and implicit conversions. So when In doubt you could also just use a good old collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all very helpfull thoughs, I've resolved my problem, the case was an instance of Attachment inside Channel Class, I had to create list of it:

```
public class ChannelSettings
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<AttachSettings> attachments { get; set; }

}
```

and then not implement it, if value is empty in that situation I'm getting result I wanted.

"{"channel":null,"username":"user","text":"Test text","attachments":null}"

It's a little bit different what I wanted at the beggining but it works the same so no futher changes needed :)